# leaflet: how to create a pane on left/right-side instead of a popup

Tags: leaflet

I would like to change the behavior when I click on a marker with a leaflet map: instead of opening a popup, would it be possible to open a larger pane to the right ? And if it is possible, how can I do it ?

Example:

[image]

Comment: [Yes](https://jdebp.eu/FGA/questions-with-yes-or-no-answers.html), it would be possible. You might want to rephrase your question.

Comment: I understand your point but... you really didn't think I wanted to know how to do it ?

Comment: No, I didn't think that. I don't read minds, so I don't know whether you're looking for: (a) confirmation of plausibility (b) generic resources that can help you achieve your goal (c) a specific resource that plays nice with your existing untold architecture/libraries/codebase/data or (d) debugging the unseen code of your previous attempt(s). And there's the non-trivial details of whether clicking on a cluster should trigger the sidebar, or only individual markers should do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several approaches. One of them is leveraging [leaflet-sidebar](https://github.com/turbo87/leaflet-sidebar/), e.g.:

```
var sidebar = L.control.sidebar('sidebar', {
    position: 'left'
});

map.addControl(sidebar);

var marker = L.marker([0,0]).addTo(map).on('click', function(){
  sidebar.setContent('Null Island').show();
});
```

See a [working demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/q20BoNSwvhHfl6tJ).

Comment: Ok, I tried it, it is kind of nice but I’m facing a problem : with multiple markers, if I click on one marker, then the sidebar opens but if I click on another marker, the sidebar closes instead of displaying the content of the new marker... you mentioned other approaches ? Could you give me one that could handle this behaviour ?

Comment: [Works for me, the sidebar doesn't hide](https://plnkr.co/edit/q20BoNSwvhHfl6tJ). And all of a sudden you're into "(d) debugging the unseen code of your previous attempt".